# Can I combine independent components from different models using PCA?

Tags: pca, svd, independent-component-analysis

I have a set of independent components for each subject in my dataset (i.e. an ica model was generated for each subject). The samples used to generate each set of ICs are aligned across subjects, and the independent components of each subject should represent the same underlying biological signals, although the exact number of ICs varies across subjects.

I would now like to combine the subject-level ICs in some way--unfortunately, I can't concatenate subjects first and run a group ica from there for the purposes of this particular analysis.

From what I've seen, the standard approach to this problem appears to be some form of clustering, where similarity between ICs is measured, and the components are then "matched" or clustered across subjects (e.g., https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/code/isctest/). In some cases, the groups of ICs are then z-scored and averaged together.

I am curious whether it makes more (or at least as much) sense to just concatenate ICs across subjects, and perform a PCA. However, I can't seem to find a single instance of this kind of approach being implemented. Is it untenable in some obvious way? Is there some fundamental problem with applying PCA to ICs?